# How do binary heaps determine their parent if it involves a half (i.e. 1.5)?

Tags: algorithm, binary-heap

I am learning about Binary Heaps and I understand that to get the left child the formula is `(2 x index)+1` and to get the right child is `(2 x index)+2`.  That makes sense to me but getting the parent node is where I don't really understand.  I know the formula for that is `(index - 1) / 2` but how does it work if it returns a half (`.5`)?

For example, if I am trying to find the parent node of index `3` then that would be `(3-1)/2` which gives you `1` so that makes sense but what about index `4`?  That would be `(4-1)/2` which gives you `1.5`.  So would the parent of index `4` be index `1` or index `2`?  Looking at a diagram like the one below it makes sense obviously because index `4` is tied to index `1` but from a mathematics standpoint I'm just not sure I understand how to handle it when halves come into play.

[image: Binary Heap]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the language in which it is implemented. In some languages `/` represents an *integer* division when the operands are integers, which is what you need. For instance, this is the case in Java where `3/2 == 1`.

If it is not, then indeed you need to truncate the result to an integer. Python for example, has the integer division operator, `//`, so that `3//2 == 1`.

Alternatively, in many of those languages you can use a shift operator: `>>1` corresponds to an integer division by 2.

So here are some equivalent ways to do it when `/` does not truncate the result to an integer:

```js
// Using bit shift
parentIndex = (childIndex - 1) >> 1
// Using ternary operator based on check whether number is odd
parentIndex = childIndex % 2 > 0 ? (childIndex - 1) / 2 : (childIndex - 2) / 2
// Use remainder of two to get to an even number that can be divided by 2
parentIndex = (childIndex - 2 + childIndex % 2) / 2
// Same thing, but the subtraction of 2 is taken out of the numerator
parentIndex = (childIndex + childIndex % 2) / 2 - 1
// Or doing the explicit truncation
parentIndex = floor((childIndex - 1) / 2)
```

Comment: So from the perspective not tied to a specific language is that number generally rounded up or down or is that something that really depends on the language and how it operates?

Comment: It is always rounded down (that's why I wrote *truncate*). Or differently put, if the current child node has an *even* index, then first subtract *two*; when it is *odd*, subtract one. Then -- in either case -- you'll have an even number which you must divide by 2. The language becomes important when to know what `/` actually does.

Comment: I added some alternative ways to my answer to come to the same result. Hope it is clear?

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did that was very helpful thanks very much!